# Mikrotik Serial Port Error "failure: port's channel is already in use"

Tags: troubleshooting, serial-port, mikrotik-routeros

### Problem:

When trying to change the settings on the MikroTik's (RB4011) serial port, the following error was received:

"***failure: port's channel is already in use***"

This error was received despite no serial cable even being connected to the serial port in the back of the router, nor was there any connection to the serial port via `/system serial-terminal serial0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

In order to clear the error to successfully modify the serial port parameters I had to:

```
/system console disable 0
```

If remote access has been enabled, additionally this must be disabled also:

```
/port remote-access disable
```

After disabling it in these two places, I was able to change the serial port's connection parameters (in this case "Flow Control") and save them.  HTH-